# Math symbol "an arrow pierces the heart"

Tags: macros, symbols, math-operators, relation-symbols

Can anyone help me create a new math symbol like in the picture below please?
[image]

I wanna use it as a binary relation symbol: «a heart pierced by an arrow from left to right» for «A **is in love with** B».

Thank you!

Comment: Your heart is not accessible to me... ;)

Answer (score 17):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\piercedheart}{%
  \relbar
  \mathrel{\mspace{-3.5mu}}
  \mathrel{\loweredheartsuit}
  \mathrel{\mspace{-7mu}}
  \rightarrow
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\loweredheartsuit}{\mathpalette\loweredheartsuit@\relax}
\newcommand{\loweredheartsuit@}[2]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\mspace{3mu}$}%
    \vskip\wd\z@
    \hbox{$\m@th#1\heartsuit$}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\piercedheart B_{A\piercedheart B}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

A first approach (which needs to be adjusted if you want to use another font, I guess):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\isinlovewith{\mathchoice
    {\relbar\mkern-8mu\raisebox{-1.2pt}{$\heartsuit$}\mkern-14mu\rightarrow}
    {\relbar\mkern-8mu\raisebox{-1.2pt}{$\heartsuit$}\mkern-14mu\rightarrow}
    {\relbar\mkern-4mu\raisebox{-0.9pt}{$\scriptstyle\heartsuit$}\mkern-9mu\rightarrow}
    {\relbar\mkern-4mu\raisebox{-0.6pt}{$\scriptscriptstyle\heartsuit$}\mkern-9mu\rightarrow}
}

\begin{document}

$\displaystyle A \isinlovewith B$\smallskip

$A \isinlovewith B$\smallskip

$\scriptstyle A \isinlovewith B$\smallskip

$\scriptscriptstyle A \isinlovewith B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Just for fun, a Ti*k*Z version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\auxheart}[1]
{%
\mathrel{\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,scale=#1,line width=0.3*#1ex,baseline=0.5*#1ex]
\draw        (0,0) -- (135:2ex) arc  (225:45:1ex) arc (135:-45:1ex) -- cycle;
\draw    (135:2ex) ++  (45:1ex)   ++ (-1ex,0) --++ (-1.75ex,0);
\draw[->] (45:2ex) ++ (135:1ex) --++ (2.75ex,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
}

\newcommand{\heart}{\mathchoice{\auxheart{0.5}}{\auxheart{0.5}}{\auxheart{0.35}}{\auxheart{0.3}}}


\begin{document}
Normal:

$A\heart B_{A\heart B}$

$\scriptstyle A\heart B_{A\heart B}$

\bigskip

\large Large (\verb|\large|):

$A\heart B_{A\heart B}$

$\scriptstyle A\heart B_{A\heart B}$

\bigskip

\huge Huge (\verb|\huge|):

$A\heart B_{A\heart B}$

$\scriptstyle A\heart B_{A\heart B}$
\end{document}
```

[image]